# How to create xml component dynamically in nativescript typescript

Tags: xml, typescript, nativescript

I want to add another component like layout, button, image, etc...

This my xml code and I want to add xml on stacklayout which ID is "chatbox":

```
<GridLayout orientation="vertical" rows="*, auto" columns="auto,*, auto"> 
    <ScrollView row="0" colSpan="3" col="0">
         <StackLayout id="chatbox">
              // I want to add XML component here dynamically
         </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Here's my current typescript code but it doesn't work. It doesn't even show compile error.

```
export function onSendButtonTap(args: EventData){

const button = <Button>args.object;
const bindingContext = <HomeViewModel>button.bindingContext;

const page = <Page>args.object;
const stack = new StackLayout();
stack.getViewById("chatbox");
const label = new Label();
label.text = "label";
stack.addChild(label);;
bindingContext.sendMessage();                }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now if you are using page reference you can use **getViewById** to access the **Stacklayout** container via its unique ID.

For example
**XML**

```
<GridLayout rows="100, *">
    <Button row="0" text="Tap to add Label" tap="onButtonTap" />
    <StackLayout row="1" id="chatbox">
        // When you tap the button the label will be added here
    </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

TypeScript

```
onButtonTap(args: EventData): void {
    console.log("Button was pressed");
    const myButton = <Button>args.object;
    const page = myButton.page; // getting page reference via the button object

    const stack = <StackLayout>page.getViewById("chatbox");
    const label = new Label();
    label.text = "My New Label";
    stack.addChild(label);;
}
```

Or you could access the Page refence via some of the Page lifecycles events

XML

```
<Page loaded="pageLoaded" class="page">
```

TypeScript

```
export function pageLoaded(args: EventData) {
    let page = <Page>args.object;
    const stack = <StackLayout>page.getViewById("chatbox");
    const label = new Label();
    label.text = "My New Label";
    stack.addChild(label);;
}
```

[Playground demo here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=sczvxX) (note that the demo is using NativeScript Core with TypeScript language). For Angular, you could use Angular ViewCHild or Page reference via DI in the componentes constructor.