# Nativescript-Vue creating dynamic elements

Tags: typescript, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I was wondering how I could create new elements dynamically like buttons, labels, or textfields which are inside a layout.

I have the following markup:

```
<AbsoluteLayout ref="abs">
    <Label :text="L('UserClockIn.info.5')" top="10" left="10" />
    <Label class="stk-table-row-data" :text="clockInTimes[0]" top="10" left="100" />
    <Label class="stk-table-row-data" :text="clockInTimes[1]" top="10" left="165" />
    <Label class="stk-table-row-data" :text="clockInTimes[2]" top="10" left="230" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

I am using nativescript-vue with typescript, i want to create a element like another label or button and add it to the absolute layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52303634/how-to-create-xml-component-dynamically-in-nativescript-typescript).

```js
import { Label } from "tns-core-modules/ui/label";

export default {
    methods: {
        addLabel() {
            var label = new Label();
            label.text = "my text";
            // label.top = 10;
            // label.left = 150;
            this.$refs.abs.nativeView.addChild(label);
        }
    }
}
```

Anyways, it looks like you're creating a grid. Have you considered using a `GridLayout`?